# Python use variable as object attribute

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use the following code:

```
def find_unknown_val(field, value, unknown_val):
temp_df = get_frame(field, value)
return temp_df.iloc[0].str(unknown_val)

print(find_unknown_val('Member_Name','McCarron,John','Supervisor_Name'))
```

This brings an error and says TypeError: 'StringMethods' object is not callable,
however it works when I use

```
def find_unknown_val(field, value, unknown_val):
temp_df = get_frame(field, value)
return temp_df.iloc[0].Supervisor_Name
```

I need to pass a variable to be used as an object attribute, any Idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The dot for attribute access is syntax, not an operator. You need an *identifier* following the dot, not an arbitrary expression.

Use `getattr` instead:

```
return getattr(temp_df.iloc[0], unknown_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use f strings

```
def find_unknown_val(field, value, unknown_val):
    temp_df = get_frame(field, value)
    return temp_df.iloc[0][f"{unknown_val}"]
```